# Select a row based on two columns one with ID and another one with specific values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to select rows based on specific column values and a unique id column in SQL

The Table I have is as follows

```
    Acc_id | Name   |  Status    | value
    ----------------------------------------
      101  |  com   |  Active    |  1
      202  |  net   |  Active    |  2
      202  |  net   |  New       |  3
      303  |  com   |  Active    |  1 
      303  |  com   |  New       |  4
      303  |  com   |  Inactive  |  2
      404  |  org   |  Active    |  5
      404  |  org   |  Inactive  |  6
      505  |  gov   |  New       |  2
      505  |  gov   |  Active    |  3
```

I would like to have the following table as a result

```
    Acc_id | Name   |  Status    | value
    ----------------------------------------
      202  |  net   |  Active    |  2
      202  |  net   |  New       |  3
      303  |  com   |  Active    |  1 
      303  |  com   |  New       |  4
      505  |  gov   |  New       |  2
      505  |  gov   |  Active    |  3
```

As you see above for the same id from column 'Acc_id' with Column 'Status' only with "New" and "Active" are selected

Comment: Show us the SQL you have tried.

Comment: What happens with the other `Acc_id` like `101` which is also `Active`?

Comment: They shouldn't be selected, only Acc_id with both Active and New as its status should be selected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Acc_id
  FROM table1
  WHERE status IN('Active', 'New')
  GROUP BY Acc_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 2
) AS t2 ON t1.Acc_id = t2.Acc_id 
WHERE t1.status IN('Active', 'New');
```

---

The `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 2` with `WHERE status IN('Active', 'New')` will ensure that the selected `Acc_id` have only two statuses `active` and `new` and no more, then `JOIN` with the original table to get the result of the columns.

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23d34/7)

This will give you:

```
| ACC_ID | NAME | STATUS | VALUE |
|--------|------|--------|-------|
|    202 |  net | Active |     2 |
|    202 |  net |    New |     3 |
|    303 |  com | Active |     1 |
|    303 |  com |    New |     4 |
|    505 |  gov |    New |     2 |
|    505 |  gov | Active |     3 |
```

Comment: +1. Your query was what i was aiming but it wasn't quite there yet. :)

Comment: @FilipeSilva - Sorry for being faster :)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal I would like to add a row under the result. The row should consist of a new Status "Existing" and the Value would be the result of (Status "Active's Value" - Status "New's Value") the other should remain the same. Eg: from the result above the third row introduced should be like this |    202 |  net | Existing|  -1 |

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE Acc_id IN 
(SELECT Acc_id FROM TABLENAME WHERE status IN ('Active','New') 
GROUP BY Acc_id Having COUNT(Acc_id)>1) AND status IN ('Active','New')
```

Comment: There is a possibility that the status is only `Active` or `New` with `count > 1`